# How Can you access a nested list that is separated by \t?

Tags: python, parsing, arraylist

```
my_list = ["VXIO456XLBB630221\t['I'", " 'Nissan'", " '2003']"]
```

how can access this list so i can get:

```
value = VXIO456XLBB630221
key = ['I', 'Nissan'", '2003']
```

```
key, value = my_list.split(\t)
```

will not work because you cant use `.split` on a list.

Comment: Where did this garbage list come from? Maybe you can fix it at the source.

Comment: No, you cannot use `split` on a list -- you have to apply it to the string.  You should already know how to access that element.  Once you make that split, then see the reference I linked for parsing the list-as-a-string.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
>>> import ast
>>> l = ','.join(my_list).split('\t')[1]
"['I', 'Nissan', '2003']"
>>> ast.literal_eval(l)
['I', 'Nissan', '2003']
```

But you should definitely ask yourself why the data looks like that in the first place.